# ¿Cómo puedo crear correctamente las tablas? JS

Tags: javascript, html, tablas

Llevo un buen rato intentando que salga el código y no me sale, aquí les dejo el código .js

```js
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
var tabla   = document.createElement("table");
var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");

for (x=1;x<=10;x++)//Tabla de multiplicar
{
 var hilera = document.createElement("tr");

 for(y=1;y<=10;y++){//Con que numero se multiplica la tabla de multiplicar

if (y==1) {
for(i=1;i<=10;i++){
celda = document.createElement("td");
textoCelda = document.createTextNode('Tabla '+i);
celda.appendChild(textoCelda);
hilera.appendChild(celda);
tblBody.appendChild(hilera);

}
celda = document.createElement("td");
textoCelda = document.createTextNode(x+' x '+y+' = '+(x*y));
celda.appendChild(textoCelda);
hilera.appendChild(celda);

} 
else {
celda = document.createElement("td");
textoCelda = document.createTextNode(y+' x '+x+' = '+(x*y));
celda.appendChild(textoCelda);
hilera.appendChild(celda);
}


}
 tblBody.appendChild(hilera);
}
tabla.appendChild(tblBody);
body.appendChild(tabla)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Tabla de multiplicar</title>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;    
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Tablas de multiplicar</h2>
<script src="prueba1.js"></script>

 


</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Solo debes sacar esta parte del for y meterlo dentro del primero para no te salga muchas veces tabla x

```
var hilera = document.createElement("tr");
celda = document.createElement("td");
textoCelda = document.createTextNode('Tabla '+x);
celda.appendChild(textoCelda);
hilera.appendChild(celda);
tblBody.appendChild(hilera);
```

dentro del segundo for no es necesario el condicional y en la parte donde muestras el resultado deberia primero imprimirse la variable ´x´

```
textoCelda = document.createTextNode(x+' x '+y+' = '+(x*y));
```

Tu codigo quedaria:

```js
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
var tabla   = document.createElement("table");
var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");

for (x=1;x<=10;x++)//Tabla de multiplicar
{
 var hilera = document.createElement("tr");
  celda = document.createElement("td");
  textoCelda = document.createTextNode('Tabla '+x);
  celda.appendChild(textoCelda);
  hilera.appendChild(celda);
  tblBody.appendChild(hilera);
 for(y=1;y<=10;y++){//Con que numero se multiplica la tabla de multiplicar
    celda = document.createElement("td");
    textoCelda = document.createTextNode(x+' x '+y+' = '+(x*y));
    celda.appendChild(textoCelda);
    hilera.appendChild(celda);
    }
 tblBody.appendChild(hilera);
}
tabla.appendChild(tblBody);
body.appendChild(tabla)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Tabla de multiplicar</title>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;    
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Tablas de multiplicar</h2>
<script src="prueba1.js"></script>

 


</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Samir, muchas gracias, algo más, cómo hago para que en lugar de arriba a abajo, como en esta imagen:
https://static2.tablasdemultiplicar.com/es/tablas-de-multiplicar-del-1-al-10.png

Comment: intentalo, si no lo logras preguntas nuevamente.